# Another way to compute the length of a curve

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

What is the length of C, where C is the graph of the function $$f(t) = \frac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2}$$
on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Is there a nice way to compute this arc length integral, *without* knowing that the function $f(t)$ is actually $\cosh(t)$?

Comment: You could do the usual calculus with the function as written, and you will get the answer in terms of that function.  In other words, you'll be doing the same math but computing everything without naming functions $\cosh(t)$ and $\sinh(t).$

Comment: you can use numerical method ,to approximate the length of f(t)

Comment: Thanks @JohnMolokach for the suggestion.  Yes, the usual calculus worked out just fine :-)

Comment: Hi @daryakhosrotash, that sounds interesting.  You mean, like, quadrature methods?  Can you elaborate just a bit?  Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the arc length formula:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2}dt.
$$
Since 
$$
f'(x)=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}\qquad\text{then}\qquad (f'(x))^2=\frac{e^{2t}-2+e^{-2t}}{4}.
$$
Then,
$$
1+(f'(x))^2=\frac{e^{2t}+2+e^{-2t}}{4}=\left(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}\right)^2.
$$
Therefore, the entire problem boils down to
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}dt
$$

Comment: By other words its curve length is it's own integral. Isn't that a peculiar property for a function to have?

Comment: @mathreadler It's a solution to the differential equation $y^2=1+(y')^2$.

Comment: Hi @MichaelBurr, I run into a small technical issue, it seems, when I use the usual calculus to integrate.  If I use the arc length formula, I usually like to derive it from the beginning, (dx)^2 + (dy)^2 = (f'(t))^2, by Pythagoras; this way, I always remember where the sqrt( ) dt comes from.  Then, *if* I knew the formula for cosh(t), I arrive at cosh(t)dt = f'(t), and I integrate |f'(t)| to get its arc length, but since cosh(t) is always positive, I just integrate cosh(t)dt with having to deal with the absolute value.  *But*, it seems that I am *missing* the dt differential ...

Comment: ...when I go for the integration of |f'(t)| with usual calculus...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't know what you're asking.  Perhaps you should ask a new question that describes your partial work.

Comment: I get that |$\frac {e^t - e^{-t}}{2}$| = |f'(t)|, which I should integrate to get the arc length.  but this number is always positive, since e^(-t) is bounded below by zero.  So, in integrating |f'(t)|, which should give the arc length, I can remove the absolute value sign, and just integrate $\frac {e^t - e^{-t}}{2}$ -- just like your integrand.  But now I don't have a dt differential, weirdly... (I must be treating either differentials incorrectly, or I have the wrong arc length formula, which I believe is just integration of |f'(t)|) ...

Comment: Ah, nevermind...the definitions on Wolfram and Wikipedia are slightly different - thanks for your help, @MichaelBurr.

Comment: I think I know what your confusion is was.  Another formula for arc length (for a parametrized curve given by $(x(t),y(t))$) is $\int_a^b\sqrt{(x'(t)^2+(y'(t))^2)}dt$.  This can be rewritten as $\int_a^b\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$.  To convert it to this problem, you have a parametrization $(t,f(t))$, whose derivatives are $1$ and $f'(t)$ (so we have the formula from above).  In the second integral above, $dx$ and $dy$ contain $dt$, namely $dx=dt$ and $dy=f'(t)dt$, so squaring this $dt$, factoring it out, and taking the square root, gives the $dt$ you were searching for.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks so much @MichaelBurr!! Have a great night, professor :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the usual thing without recognizing the coshine function.
The key observation you have to do is that $1+f'(t)^2=\frac14(e^t+e^{-t})^2$, which might even be easier without the hyperbolic functions, and integrate as usual.

Comment: ok, got it - thanks @JoonasIlmavirta.

Answer (score 1):

element of curve length is $\sqrt{\Delta x^2 +\Delta y^2}$ so you can approximate by $\Delta x=0.1 \text or \Delta x=0.01 \\from\\x=0\\to\\x=2\pi$ for calculation . Alse you can choose many standard method to find this integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\Delta x^2 +\Delta y^2}\\ =\Sigma_{i=1}^{i=n}\sqrt{\Delta x^2 +\Delta y^2}$